# Solr EdgeNGramFilterFactory and minGramSize

Tags: solr

Is there a way to use EdgeNGramFilterFactory and keep searching exact terms?

I want keep minGramSize = 4, but if I search for "pad", I want get results of "mouse pad", because is a exact term inside the phrase.

```xml
<fieldType name="ngran_text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" 
            minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
    <filter class="solr.BrazilianStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: You should remove `side="front"` from the EdgeNGramFilterFactory, since (a) this will break during an update and (b) front is the default anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would want to have is a `preseverOriginal` flag with the `EdgeNGramFilter` which is not yet implemented. There is [a feature request for Solr (SOLR-5332)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5332) which addresses that issue. The feature is planned for version 5.1. Version 5.0 has just been released (20 February 2015). So it may take a while until you can just use it, after you have made an upgrade.

If waiting and upgrading is not an option, you can work around this via using

- a second field with a more regular analyzer
- [the copyField command](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields) in your schema to populate the field
- the [dismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser) or better [edismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser) query handler to address both fields for the same search query